# How to avoid CupertinoApp Widget functionality on a spesific widget?

Tags: flutter, widget

I am using CupertinoApp Widget on the root of my widget tree instead of MaterialApp. I like to have the functionality of CupertinoApp on widgets. But in some cases, I also want to avoid this functionality on a spesific widget. For example, I am using a titleNavigationBar that can be scrollable horizontally, and has a identifier underline in each item. Because of CupertinoApp Widget, a scrollBar is appearing and overflow the identifier underline. How to avoid functionality of cupertinoApp Widget on specific widget.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting your own style for the widget ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RawScrollbar instead and set the thumbColor to whatever color you like.

```
 RawScrollbar(
                thumbColor: Colors.redAccent,
                radius: Radius.circular(20),
                thickness: 5,
                child: //scrollable widget
                       )
```

Comment: Why you are using another scrollbar widget, I didn't get it.  I am not just using titleNavigationBar for the titles, it also has body.